# Null affecting Map<String, dynamic>

Tags: dart, null, flutter-futurebuilder, stream-builder

```
child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: _address,

    builder: ( BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
      print(snapshot);
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done && snapshot.hasData && 
        snapshot.data != null) {
        !snapshot.hasData;
        return Center(
          child: circularProgress(),
        );
      } else {
        return snapshot.data?.docs.length == 0 ?
        Container() : ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return AddressDesign(
                currentIndex: address.count,
                value: index,
                addressID: widget.addressID,
                totalAmount: widget.totalAmount!,
                clientUID: widget.clientUID!,
                  model: Address.fromJson(

                  snapshot.data?.docs[index].data()! as Map<String, dynamic>
              ),
              );
            });
      }

    },),);
```

[image]

I have tried removing Null safety from the Model class but it only made it worse.
What i would like to know is how can i display data on the page without it returning a null value.
Please i need help!

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your error messages, code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code)

Comment: It looks like you have your if/else mixed up. When your snapshot has data (`snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null`) you're returning a circular progress indicator, and when it *doesn't* have data, you're returning the list view. Does it work if you switch them around?